# SQL Server : row_number partition does not reset counter

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, window-functions

In the data below d1 changes to d2 and then back to d1, Partitioning is over column d, so partition correctly resets from d1->d2 in row# 2 and rn = 1. I'd expect partition to reset also for d2->d1, i.e  record #3 should have rn = 1 as well.

How can I fix this query?

```
SELECT
    t.*, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d ORDER BY id)
FROM   
    (VALUES (1, 'd1'), (2, 'd2'), (3, 'd1')) t (id, d)
ORDER BY
    id
```

[image]

Comment: That *is* correct; that is the **2nd** row for the value `d1`; the first was when `id` had the value `1`.

Comment: What's the point of order by in partition then. Column d changes so it has to be new partition for the third row as well

Comment: To **partition** the data... It's doing exactly what it says, put the data into groups. 1 group for each distinct value of `d` in this case, and there are only two different values of `d`, `'d1'` and `'d2'` and 3 rows, so one of those rows is going to have a value of 2; the 2nd row for a specific value. In this case, when the `id` has the value `3` then that is the **2nd** row for the value `'d1'`. It is working exactly as expected, and as documented.

Comment: You could just divide the overall `row_number() - 1` by 2 to get a grouped row number

Answer (score 0):

At a guess you want to start the row number each time the value of `d` changes when ordering the data by the value of `id`, which is *not* the same as a row number per value of `d`. If that is the case, one method is the below:

```sql
SELECT id,
       d,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) -
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d ORDER BY id ASC) AS RN
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: This returns 1 for rows 2 & 3, I;m looking for something that resets every time value changes from the previous row.

Answer (score 0):

This gets the job done but seems too clunky.

```
select 
t.*, 
lagd=lag(d) over (order by id),
change= (case when d= (lag(d) over (order by id)) then 0 else 1 end)
FROM   (VALUES          (1,'d1' ),
                        (2,'d2' ),
                        (3,'d1' ),
                        (4,'d2' ),
                        (5,'d2' )
                        ) t (id, d)
order by id
```